# Save and load arrays - Objective c

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I am developing an app and needs to save arrays, but I'm not sure how I can do it. Does anyone know how I could save and load arrays in Xcode Objective-c?

Thanks!

Comment: You can read/write as a [property list](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/ReadWritePlistData/ReadWritePlistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH8-SW1), or you can read/write as [JSON](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very broad question, but here is a very simple answer.

To save your array to file:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:array toFile:fileName];
```

To load your array from that file:

```
NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:fileName];
```

These calls depend on the fact that NSArray implements NSCoding (through NSSecureCoding).